# HTML Bold music sharp sign

Tags: html, symbols

I've noticed that music sharp sign (♯ vs **♯**) is unresponsive to attempts to make it bold with tags like `<strong></strong>`, `<b></b>`.

Why? And is there any alternative way to make it bold?

The strange thing is that music flat sign (♭ vs **♭**) behaves totally fine with `<strong></strong>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all Unicode characters are format-able.

Basically when a font is made bold, and that font does not have a built in bold counterpart the processor decides what to do.

In this case a web browser will add additional pixels starting from the bottom left to the font or symbol but only if the characters white space is not over-compromised. Specifically, you have a sharp sign and the square in the center when emboldened would compromise the readability of the symbol. This process would make the symbol a square with some pointy bits and maybe less than a pixel of white space. The font processor (browser) just wont allow that to happen.

---

You have a few options:

1. Try a text-shadow in CSS
2. Use a font that has a better version of this symbol that would permit emboldening or better yet is already nice thick and clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using CSS text-shadow to simulate the boldness.

```css
text-shadow:
   -1px -1px 0 #000,  
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
     1px 1px 0 #000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it bold by using any other kind of font in CSS. Used the Algerian font. It worked. It changed into Algerian. So find a suitable font style and apply it.